# How to install apt-get on AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apt-get

I am using an instance of AWS EC2. I want to use **apt-get** command, but it throws an error: 'apt-get not found'

How do i get to use apt-get command?

Comment: Are you sure you are using Ubuntu?

Comment: its a linux machine for sure. how do i check the distribution?

Comment: What is your user name: `ec2-user` or `ubuntu` in the terminal after you ssh?

Comment: it shows ec2-user. and what does it mean?

Comment: @n0obcoder share the contents of this </etc/os-release>.

Answer (score 8):

For exact details of your Linux distro you can use command

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

Its example output for **Ubuntu** (default user is `ubuntu`) is:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

while for **Amazon Linux 2** (default user is `ec2-user`):

```
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
```

Since it seems you are using Amazon Linux 2, you should use `yum` to install and updated your packaged, not `apt` nor `apt-get`,e.g.:

```
sudo yum update
```

Alternatively, when you create your instance, **choose Ubuntu image** for your it, rather then default Amazon Linux 2.

Comment: NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"

ok yes, mine is amazon linux 2

Comment: @n0obcoder Thus you either have to use `yum` or make new ubuntu-based instance if you prefer working with apt and apt-get.

Comment: i am trying to install tensorflow_model_server. But i cant install it using 'sudo yum install tensorflow_model_server'